# BX Slider Carousel Arrow not Working

Tags: html, bxslider

I used BX Slider Carousel on my site, every thing works fine but the arrow was not moving left and right. 
Have tried with many ways but no use.. 
Here is the front end link: http://rcpixel.com/demo/bed.html

Thanks

Comment: Please include relevant code, that will help us help you.

Comment: There was big code.. can you please check on viewsource @Lima

Comment: There are lot of mistake in your code as say @DMVamsi. you need to first correct you code.

Comment: Can you able to give me the hint where the mistake is @abidkhanweb

Comment: There are some incorrect source path, following this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print04fc.css?5088" media="print" />` `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.unveil.js?4900"></script>` `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/enterprise/wishlist04fc.js?5088"></script>` `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/enterprise/catalogevent04fc.js?5088"></script>`

Comment: No.. its not the mistake.. even correcting those paths also its not working.. @abidkhanweb

Comment: I am finding the same @DMVamsi